# Is it possible to get the data from the database and put it on a textview while it is on a OnDateChangeListener?

Tags: android

I want my textview to show the amount inputted on that day when I click a different date. But when I click a date it always shows no amount spent also I have tried if the `datetimedisplayed == databasedate` and still nothing happens.

This is the code to show the amount on the textview

```
dateTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datedisplay);
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
dateTimeDisplay.setText(date);
calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
res = myDb.getAllData();
if (res.getCount() == 0) {
  total.setText("NO AMOUNT SPENT");
  return;
}
while (res.moveToNext()) {
  total.setText("Php: " + res.getString(2));
}
```

This is the code where the date changes when I click on different dates in the calendar but it will only show no amount spent

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
    date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    dateTimeDisplay.setText(date);
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
      total.setText("NO AMOUNT SPENT");
      return;
    } else if (res.getString(1) == date) {
      total.setText("Php: " + res.getString(2));
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not related to setOnDateChangeListener the problem is your database is no data. Make Sure Your database is data and check date format is the same as the date column in the database

Comment: my database has data though i can access the data and see it on sqlitedbmanager also i can put it on the textview but when i click another date it just doesnt work